# PyQt5 PushButton not showing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This is the code I am using and the button doesn't show and it only shows a blank window. There is no error in the console.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


import sys

def start():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(128,102)
    w.move(0, 0)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hi")
    btn.move(50, 50)
    btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

start()
```

This is the window it shows
[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the parent argument to the constructor. The parent argument causes the button to be owned by Qt, not PyQt. `btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hi", w)` should work.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

Any widget you want to be shown needs to be parented, either directly or indirectly, to the widget you want it to appear in.

The common way to do this is by assigning your widget a layout and adding other widgets or sublayouts to it.

```
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Hi')
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)  # Parents layout to widget
layout.addWidget(button)
widget.show()
```

In this example, `widget` is indirectly assigned as the parent to `button` through `layout`

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


import sys

def start():
    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w       = QWidget()
    w.resize(128,102)
    w.move(0, 0)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')

    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton (w)
    btn.move(50, 50)
    btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
    btn.setText ('Hi')

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

start()
```